# Linq Join list with itself distinctly

Tags: linq

I have a list of values, say *A, B and C*. I want to join it with itself to get all distinct combinations considering a value can't join itself and that *A-B* is the same as *B-A*

The end result should be
*A-B, A-C, B-C*
and **not** a full cross product
*A-A, A-B, A-C, B-A, B-B, B-C, C-A, C-B, C-C*

In traditional code, I came up with the following

```cs
var myList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
for(var i=0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    for (var j=i+1; j < myList.Count; j++)
        //Do Something
```

Is there any LINQ equivalent? I'm mainly seeking a more meaningful and human readable implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/eoincampbell/combinatorics

Answer (score 2):

I found one way to do it in LInQ but I don't think it qualifies as more meaningful nor readable and mostly, from a performance perspective, it is 3 to 7 (from the first test run I did with only A, B, C in a fixed List) times slower.

```
from item1 in myList
from item2 in myList.SkipWhile(x => x != item1).Skip(1)
select (item1, item2)
```

I first thought the main reason the performance was *that* bad with the LInQ versions was becaus it still ran a full cross product but my simplistic benchmark seems to disagree.

|  | Count | V1 | V2 | Ratio | V1/item | V2/item | V1/item^2 | V2/item^2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 125 | 455 | 3,640 | 12,500 | 45,500 | 1,250 | 4,550 |
| 2 | 10 | 124 | 440 | 3,548 | 12,400 | 44,000 | 1,240 | 4,400 |
| 3 | 30 | 976 | 3034 | 3,109 | 32,533 | 101,133 | 1,084 | 3,371 |
| 4 | 30 | 975 | 3023 | 3,101 | 32,500 | 100,767 | 1,083 | 3,359 |
| 5 | 50 | 2702 | 8088 | 2,993 | 54,040 | 161,760 | 1,081 | 3,235 |
| 6 | 50 | 2763 | 8155 | 2,952 | 55,260 | 163,100 | 1,105 | 3,262 |
| 7 | 70 | 5393 | 15708 | 2,913 | 77,043 | 224,400 | 1,101 | 3,206 |
| 8 | 70 | 5416 | 15740 | 2,906 | 77,371 | 224,857 | 1,105 | 3,212 |
| 9 | 90 | 8993 | 25908 | 2,881 | 99,922 | 287,867 | 1,110 | 3,199 |
| 10 | 90 | 8983 | 25869 | 2,880 | 99,811 | 287,433 | 1,109 | 3,194 |

Benchmark code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Benchmarks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i+=2)
            {
                CrossProduct(i, Enumerable.Range(1,10*i).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList());
            }

            _ = Console.Read();
        }

        private static void CrossProduct(int iterations, IList<string> data)
        {
            var v1 = CrossProductV1(data);
            var v2 = CrossProductV2(data);
            Console.WriteLine($"{iterations} | DataCount: {data.Count}\t| V1:{v1}* | V2:{v2}");
            v2 = CrossProductV2(data);
            v1 = CrossProductV1(data);
            Console.WriteLine($"{iterations+1} | DataCount: {data.Count}\t| V1:{v1}  | V2:{v2}*");
        }

        private static long CrossProductV1(IList<string> data)
        {
            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (var repeatIndex = 0; repeatIndex < 100000; repeatIndex++)
            {
                List<object> result = new List<object>();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
                    for (var j = i + 1; j < data.Count; j++)
                        result.Add((data[i], data[j]));
            }
            return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
        private static long CrossProductV2(IList<string> data)
        {
            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (var repeatIndex = 0; repeatIndex < 100000; repeatIndex++)
            {
                List<object> result = null;
                result = (from item1 in data
                          from item2 in data.SkipWhile(x => x != item1).Skip(1)
                          select (object)(item1, item2)).ToList();
            }

            return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```